# Postgres running in kubernetes throws an error PANIC could not locate a valid checkpoint record

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, psql, citus

I am running postgres in kubernetes and I am seeing the below error.

```
PANIC could not locate a valid checkpoint record
```

How do I recover from this error as it goes in to crashloobackoff and I couldn't find a way to recover and also how do I make sure that there shouldn't be possible data corruption in future whenever I make any changes to pod and the pod restarts. can I use any preStop hooks in the container?

Comment: I can't see any useful information in this question I'm afraid. I don't think anyone will be able to help. You haven't said how your pod is setup, shown the logs before the error or anything.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [postgresql error PANIC: could not locate a valid checkpoint record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8799474/postgresql-error-panic-could-not-locate-a-valid-checkpoint-record)

Comment: You can also check this StackOverflow [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62931646/19371698)