# PostgreSQL container on Docker Swarm corrupts in some way after several days of uptime, consistently

Tags: postgresql, docker

I have a PostgreSQL container set up for a Docker Swarm, such that it only runs on one node in the service so that other members on the swarm can communicate with it. However, after about 3-10 days of uptime, the database will eventually corrupt in some manner.

Usually, and most recently, it is this:

```
PostgreSQL Database directory appears to contain a database; Skipping initialization
2024-02-04 02:44:42.774 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 16.1 (Debian 16.1-1.pgdg120+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 12.2.0-14) 12.2.0, 64-bit
2024-02-04 02:44:42.774 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
2024-02-04 02:44:42.774 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
2024-02-04 02:44:42.779 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
2024-02-04 02:44:42.786 UTC [30] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2024-02-03 12:13:41 UTC
2024-02-04 02:44:42.786 UTC [30] LOG:  invalid record length at 31/39646860: expected at least 24, got 0
2024-02-04 02:44:42.786 UTC [30] LOG:  invalid checkpoint record
2024-02-04 02:44:42.786 UTC [30] PANIC:  could not locate a valid checkpoint record
2024-02-04 02:44:42.923 UTC [1] LOG:  startup process (PID 30) was terminated by signal 6: Aborted
2024-02-04 02:44:42.924 UTC [1] LOG:  aborting startup due to startup process failure
2024-02-04 02:44:42.925 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is shut down
```

...though I have seen other errors about the postmaster.pid lock still being active.

Some people I've asked have posited that it could be the disk. I'm on a DigitalOcean virtual node, which seems to make it difficult/impossible to run the disk checking tools I could find, but I have recently asked them to move me to a new hypervisor, which happened about a week ago, and this issue persists, so I am not confident that is the issue.

Here is the Docker Swarm configuration:

```yaml
version: "3.9"
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:16.1
    ports:
      - 5432:5432 # Not *usually* on here
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: "<password>"
    networks:
      - swarm
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints:
          - node.labels.has_database==true # Only one node has this
      replicas: 1
    volumes:
      - /home/postgresql-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
networks:
  swarm:
    driver: overlay
    external: true
    attachable: true
```

And here is the only non-commented lines of my postgresql.conf:

```
listen_addresses = '*'
max_connections = 300                   # (change requires restart)
shared_buffers = 128MB                  # min 128kB
dynamic_shared_memory_type = posix      # the default is usually the first option
max_wal_size = 1GB
min_wal_size = 80MB
log_timezone = 'Etc/UTC'
datestyle = 'iso, mdy'
timezone = 'Etc/UTC'
lc_messages = 'en_US.utf8'              # locale for system error message
lc_monetary = 'en_US.utf8'              # locale for monetary formatting
lc_numeric = 'en_US.utf8'               # locale for number formatting
lc_time = 'en_US.utf8'                  # locale for time formatting
default_text_search_config = 'pg_catalog.english'
```

The box with the database has 155GB of storage in total, and at the moment 96GB of it is available.

This issue has also persisted from PostgreSQL 15 to PostgreSQL 16, where I tried completely wiping the database and postgresql-data and starting over from scratch to make this work.

I have no consistent reproduction of this yet. I've tried forcefully calling reboot on the server while active data is coming in, or shutting off the DigitalOcean node, scaling the service node to zero, etc, but PostgreSQL can recover every time I do.

Any help would be greatly appreciated...this has been frustrating me for several months :(

Comment: check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60604699/postgres-k8s-panic-could-not-locate-a-valid-checkpoint-record-crashloopbac

Comment: That doesn't look useful here. I know how to reset the WAL, but surely it corrupting every week is not expected behavior.

Comment: This shows the container restarting.  Why did the container need to be restarted? What is in the log for when the container shutdown prior to the restart?

Comment: Unfortunately it seems like my logs fill up before I can see, or something...the earliest I see is this restart loop. I'm going to tune that up and see if I can get anything more useful out of it.